# VBA function return 0

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have a function with working fine.

One missing peace is to in case of result of `formula = 0` put a text "Full". As currently if calculation result is 0 formula showing 0.0 in the cell.

multiple if sc = 0  then but no result

```
Function StockCover(Stock, DispatchRange As Range) As Double
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim cell, mSt, SC

    Application.Volatile False
    SC = 0

    If Stock > 0 Then
        For Each cell In DispatchRange
            MySum = MySum + cell.Value
            mSt = Stock - cell.Value

            If mSt > 0 Then
                SC = SC + 1
                Stock = Stock - cell.Value
            Else
                SC = SC + Stock / cell.Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If

    StockCover = SC
End Function
```

If result of calculation for cell is 0 then put text "Full"

Comment: Please indent code correctly when pasting it here. It's so hard to read and quickly digest when laid out poorly.

Comment: You are returning a double so that will need to be a variant or a string, if the cell range is set to number format, that will also need to change. That said, ```If SC= 0 then SC = 'Full'``` before you return the value.

Comment: Thank You @Mathieu Guindon its any chance you can adjust my code as Im afraid its little bit above my coding skills. Thank You again for your help

Comment: Your return type needs to be `Variant`, too. That way you can return a `String` or a `Double`, and Excel (and VBA) will understand either as such.

Comment: I have managed to find solution by adding before sub end IF StockCover = 0 THEN StockCover = "FULL" and adding stockcover as string. But thank you guys for help !!:)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try changing your type of function to Variant , and just input an IF on it

```
Function StockCover(Stock, DispatchRange As Range) As Variant
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim cell, mSt, SC

    Application.Volatile False
    SC = 0

    If Stock > 0 Then
        For Each cell In DispatchRange
            MySum = MySum + cell.Value
            mSt = Stock - cell.Value

            If mSt > 0 Then
                SC = SC + 1
                Stock = Stock - cell.Value
            Else
                SC = SC + Stock / cell.Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If

    if SC = 0 then 
          StockCover = "FULL"
    else 
        StockCover  = vba.cdbl(SC)
    end if 
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

`On Error Resume Next` isn't your friend. Forget it exists. It's useful for when you need to "swallow" an inevitable runtime error, and you immediately handle the error case and restore error handling with `On Error GoTo 0`. Sticking `On Error Resume Next` at the top of a procedure is like saying "I don't care if this works or not, whatever error happens, I don't want to hear about it - just merrily keep running along and whatever happens, happens". As you can guess, that's far from ideal for debugging.

> ```
> Function StockCover(Stock, DispatchRange As Range) As Double
> ```

If the function needs to return a `String`, then it can't return a `Double`. If it needs to return a `Double`, then it can't return a `String`. I would strongly advise against making a UDF that returns some magical string value, but if you want to do that, then you need to return a `Variant`.

`Variant` is like a little box in which you can put anything you want: a `String`, a `Double`, an `Error`, or even an `Object` reference.

Whenever you don't declare an explicit type for an identifier, VBA understands it as a `Variant`, and will "helpfully" change the variant subtype on a whim for you - so if you assign a `String` to a `Variant`, it's a `Variant/String`. If you then assign a `Double` to that same variant, it becomes a `Variant/Double`.

> ```
>  SC = SC + Stock / cell.Value
> ```

Clearly `Stock` is intended to be something numeric, not "whatever you throw at me" - declare it as such. Also consider making the function explicitly `Public`, and pass the parameters `ByVal` since you don't need them to be `ByRef` (the implicit default):

```
Public Function StockCover(ByVal Stock As Double, ByVal DispatchRange As Range) As Variant
```

Same for the local variables:

> ```
> Dim cell, mSt, SC
> ```

They're all implicit `Variant`, but you're not using them that way - this is an invitation for bugs! Be explicit, and declare them where they're used so you always see your local variables in their context (also make sure `Option Explicit` is specified at the top of the module - code shouldn't be allowed to compile with undeclared variables).

```
Public Function StockCover(ByVal Stock As Double, ByVal DispatchRange As Range) As Variant
    Application.Volatile False

    Dim SC As Double ' TODO: use meaningful name
    SC = 0 'NOTE: redundant assignment, Double initializes at 0 anyway

    If Stock > 0 Then

        Dim cell As Range
        For Each cell In DispatchRange

            If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then

                Dim runningTotal As Double
                runningTotal = runningTotal + cell.Value

                Dim runningDiff As Double
                runningDiff = Stock - cell.Value

                If runningDiff > 0 Then
                    SC = SC + 1
                    Stock = Stock - cell.Value
                Else
                    SC = SC + Stock / cell.Value
                    Exit For
                End If

            End If

        Next

    End If

    StockCover = IIf(SC = 0, "Full", SC)

End Function
```